# Stream reading variations in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I've seen [this code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654324/859154) which  - reads from a Stream into a buffer :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    //...
}
```

But looking at  the second parameter of `stream.Read(..,0,..)` which is the *[zero-based byte offset in **buffer** at which to begin storing the data read from the current stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx).*

So is the offset is 0 each time ? who said it doesn't overwrite data at those indexes?

On the contrary : I also saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571057/859154) :

```
 int read, offset = 0;
     while(count > 0 && (read = source.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0) {
        offset += read;
        count -= read;
    }
```

So here the offset is offsetted after each reading ( which seems more logical to me)

But I must be missing something :

Was my observation was right? When should I use each case ?

NB , my pov is network stream : sending file.

Comment: I don't understand. Yes first sample overwrites and second one adds offset and doesn't overwrite. What is your question?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel if you send a file over the network and keep writing overriting 0 index , who gaurntee that receiver already read that first bytes that were at the start of the stream ?

Comment: messages send normally have a 'End Of Text' char (see ascii table) which tells you the message has finished. the first is usually used when there is less memory available ( also since you have predefined the buffer's length, you may get an `index of out of range error` anyway from second example)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your both examples shows reading data whereas you talk about writing data. Both are very different things. How do you relate those two?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My question is pretty simple : when should I use which mechanism of filling a buffer while reading. that's all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're both code samples useful, just in different scenario. Let's pick your first example to add some code:

```
Socket socket = ...;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    socket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, bytesRead , SocketFlags.None, null, null);
    // Wait for completion doing something else? 
}
```

In this case `buffer` is **reused** each time then yes, data will be overwritten and it's the intended behavior because you read a chunk at time, you use it and you go on.

Your second example is pretty different: you're filling a `buffer` with read data but you don't read all data all together, you read a smaller chunk each time then `offset` in target `buffer` must increase.

How they differ? In first case buffer can be as small as you want (ideally even one byte), multiple read will consume input stream. In second case buffer must be big enough to accommodate all data you need.

```
// Note we need to know file size in advance and buffer must be big enough
// to accommodate all data we need
int read, offset = 0;
while(count > 0 && (read = source.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0) {
    socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset , read, SocketFlags.None, null, null);

    // Here we don't need to wait BeginSend() completes. 

    offset += read;
    count -= read;
}
```

Which one is better? Hard to say, if you allocate all memory in one shot then seldom you need to read chunk by chunk increasing `offset` (only case I can think about is a performance optimization because of block size on input stream or when you want to - in parallel - start some processing on received data while reading new ones). In contrast to allocate a buffer big enough to accommodate all data has at least two big drawbacks:

- you **must know file size** in advance (and it's not always true);
- if file is big enough then you'll run **out of memory**.

In general (IMO) if first method (reusing same buffer) is pretty good in most situations, **performance gain** you may have from a single read (and non blocking send) **is negligible** in most network scenario and drawbacks are serious. To summarize:

```
                               1                2
Unknown file size              yes              no
Can run out of memory          yes              no
Parallel processing friendly   no               yes
Performance optimized          no               yes
```

Of course you may also "mix" both methods: one big **circular buffer with multiple smaller reads**, for each read you advance offset *pointer* starting a new read and in parallel do processing on the previous one(s). With this you may have advantages from both methods but it's little bit more tricky to tune (because of concurrent access and possibly overlapping read/write).

Comment: So which approach would you use for sending files over networkstream ?(first?)

Comment: first - that way if you have a mis-message, you don't have to resend everything again (as you are dealing with line by line)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I tried to explain in answer but in short: almost always first method may be better (yes, "almost" and "may be" are not used by case).

Answer (score 3):

You've missed an important part of that original answer:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    // Use the data you've read
}
```

You use the data that you've read into the buffer so it can then be thrown away (replaced). This is useful if you've got a potentially big stream and don't want to suffer from memory issues.

In your 2nd example you'll be able to read the entire contents of the stream into a buffer and deal with the contents as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

The two samples is right.I read [the link code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654298/filestream-read-write-methods-limitation/5654324#5654324).

```
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    // Use the data you've read once you have received,and then thow it away.
    //So,you can cover the old data.
}

while(count > 0 && (read = source.Read(buffer, offset, count)) > 0) {
    offset += read;
    count -= read;
    //received all data from the stream,and then use them.
    //So you can't cover the old data.
}
```

Two methods are available.